# Angular2 constructor not running

Tags: angular, typescript, constructor

I have the following code:

```
// Imports
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      templateUrl: './app/my.component.html'
    })

    export class MyComponent{

     s: string = "Test";

      constructor() {
        console.log(this.s)            
      } 

    }
```

After I run my application console.log doesn't show 'Test' text. What I do wrong ?

Comment: Where is the component being loaded?

Comment: I load component in the app.module

Comment: Are you routing to it? There's nothing wrong with your code, and if the component is being displayed in your app it will show the console.log().

Comment: Yes, my.component.html is display properly, but in console message from constructor doesn't show

Comment: Definitely not enough information here. It's worth noting that the `s: string` declaration is redundant. `s = "Test"` implies string typing. Here's a working plunker using the information you've provided: https://plnkr.co/edit/joqYD2wybpoFLaMlgDiH?p=preview.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your component in the app.module file under:
@NgModule({
  declarations:
      MyComponent
})
And you should add it somewhere, in example to the index.HTML.

Also best practice is to keep your component and its related HTML and CSS under the same folder.

You can use the following GitHub project as reference:
https://github.com/gothinkster/angular-realworld-example-app

Comment: Ok, I have the same files structure like in above github code. And I also declared my component in app.module. But my constructor still not running.

Comment: Can you post your index.html file?

Answer (score -1):

Page navigation happens?? Can you see the HTML page??custom methods in myComponent is working?? Have you checked in debug mode inside constructor ?? Keep the hard coded console (console.log("success"))Instead of console.log(this.a) and check whether string "success" printing or not.